# Python - How to avoid dependency of buffer variable in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, dependencies

I want to implement a very easy Insertion-Sort algorithm in python where i can sort an array row/column-wise in dependency of the nth element of the row/column

```
A = [(2,1,2),(1,4,1),(3,2,3)]
```

becomes to

```
A = [(1,4,1),(2,1,2),(3,2,3)]
```

when sorting row-wise and dependency of the A[0]

So i wrote a function

```
import numpy as np
'''
Algorithm to sort array row/columnwise
A : numpy array, x : axis on which to sort (0:=rows, 1:=colums in 2D)
nth : nth element of array to sort
'''

def insertion_sort(A, x, nth):

if x == 0:
    for i in range(1, np.size(A, axis=x)):
        buffer = A[i]
        j = i-1
        while j >= 0 and A[j][nth] > buffer[nth]:
            A[j+1] = A[j]
            j -= 1
        A[j+1] = buffer
return A
```

Which i call with

```
A = np.array([(2,1,2),(1,4,1),(3,2,3)])

print(insertion_sort(A,0,0))
```

But i get a bug because buffer changes with the dependency of i in the line

```
buffer = A[i]
```

Which affects

```
A[j+1] = buffer
```

at the end of the loop. I really don't think that this is supposed to happen? Did I miss something?
Output of the function is

```
[[2 1 2]
 [2 1 2]
 [3 2 3]]
```

which is wrong.

Comment: it is for practice, i have to implement different sorting algorithms

Answer (score 0):

NumPy arrays are stored in contiguous memory locations. Therefore, `A[j+1] = A[j]` cannot be done by copying memory address (doing so would cause `A[j+1]` and `A[j]` to have the same addresses), and hence the assignment is done by copying the value.

You may check the memory location of `buffer` with `print(buffer.__array_interface__['data'][0])`